# ShinobiChart throw an exception when points in SChartColumnSeries is touched

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have downlaod the example projects and tried, and found a problem. I ran the HandlingSelection project, it worked well, but I changed the code

```
lineSeries.selectionMode = SChartSelectionPoint;
```

then the APP throw an Exception everytime when I touched the Mushrooms of 2013.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableOrderedSet addObject:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced the same issue and have just fixed it. This will be that your

```
- (void)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chartIn toggledSelectionForPoint:(SChartDataPoint *)dataPoint inSeries:(SChartSeries *)series atPixelCoordinate:(CGPoint)pixelPoint
```

will be looking at an incorrect index. This can be fixed by using `index = 0;`

(or whatever index you have)

in your

```
- (SChartSeries*)sChart:(ShinobiChart*)chart seriesAtIndex:(int)index method
```